# How to use imported third-party js (not addon/npm package) in controller/component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, import, ember-cli

I have put my js files `eva.min.js/feather.min.js` and so on in **vendor** dir, then I imported them in **ember-cli-build.js** `app.import('vendor/eva.min.js')`. But how to use it?

I tried something like `import eva from 'eva'/'eva.min'/'eva.min.js'` or `import Eva from 'eva';` and so on, but it doesn't work.

```
  app.import('vendor/eva.min.js');
  app.import('vendor/bootstrap.min.js');
  app.import('vendor/feather.min.js');
  app.import('vendor/popper.min.js');
  app.import('vendor/jquery-slim.min.js');
  app.import('vendor/swipe.js');
```

```
import Swipe from 'swipe';
```

Console usually gives me the **could not find the module** error. 
And I don't have a deep background in programming, so I would highly appreciate if you explained the problem as simple as possible.

UPD: I found all js code as npm package (it happens that the js files weren't third-party)

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/feather
https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-slim
https://www.npmjs.com/package/swipe
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eva-icons
```

But all your responses were helpful. Anyway in the near future I expect to use third-party libraries.

Comment: you no need this line `import Swipe from 'swipe';` since `swipe.js` is already been imported in your `ember-cli-build.js`

Comment: If you use a recent version of ember.js / ember-cli I would strongly recommend to use [`ember-auto-import`](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import). Otherwise it depends on the module format the third-party library is using (AMD, CommonJS, UMD) and the ember-cli version.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to use [scriptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs) and it allows you to load any javascript into your component in the following way: (I am using Yammer as an example)

```
    import $scriptjs from 'scriptjs';
    componentDidUpdate() {
       //script loader
       setTimeout(function(){
         $scriptjs('https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js', 
         () => {
            window.yam.connect.embedFeed(YammerHelper.loadComments());
         });
       }, 1000);
    }
```

You should get the idea how to consume it. Check their docs with lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution. But one way of using the third party js is,

1) say you have a function in your js file `vendor/third-party.js`

```
someFunction = function (element) {
  ...
  console.log("works")
};
```

2) Then import it in your `ember-cli-build.js`

```
...
app.import('vendor/third-party.js');
...
```

3) After importing `restart` your server.

Use the function directly in your controller/component as

```
window["someFunction"]
```

Comment: This is only true if your third party library registers itself on global `window` object.

Comment: yes importing it in ember-cli-build.js auto-registers on the global window object. Isn't it?

Comment: It only includes it in the build. The library might register itself on global window object (which is bad) or not. It might be available to use as JavaScript module with `import` API or not. It may require to define a specific transformer to do so. This is covered by [old ember-cli docs](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies) but I would strongly recommend [ember-auto-import](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import) as it's way less complex.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the JavaScript library being used explicitly supports the `import X from 'y'` syntax then when you import in the build using the `app.import` syntax you just use it in your app just as the plugin documentation describes.

So for `Swipe` you would do the following.
Based on this documentation: https://github.com/thebird/Swipe

```
// ember-cli-build.js
app.import('myswipe.js`);
```

```
// component.js
/* global Swipe */ // This silences the linter from throwing errors...
classNames: ['swipe'],
didInsertElement() {
   this._swipe = Swipe(this.element, {
       option1: option1
   });
}
```

```
// component.hbs
<div class='swipe-wrap'>
    {{yield}}
</div>
```

This codes creates a component to control your swipe plugin.
This code would create a swipe object and isolate it to the component.

Again when you use the `app.import` you are just loading the library on boot. The library does whatever it says it will do in the docs. Sometimes they register a global object, sometimes they dont.